# Windows Phone 8 Company Hub won't distribute to multiple phones

Tags: windows-phone-8

Just finished a company hub app for my Companies windows 8 phones. I have a few different phones i'm testing with, all the same model. One test phone works completely fine with absolutely no issue. However my problem is the company hub app works fine with one phone and has issues on the other 2 phones I'm testing with. For example, one phone successfully installed the company hub app but will not install the company program we have. The other phone will not install the aetx key created however the other two phones installed it without issue. The apps have all been signed properly, like I said the hub app and the app the hub distributes works fine on one test phone. Any ideas?

UPDATE
So an update. I've republished the app, resigned new xap files. I was able to get the install completed on phone 2. So now phone 1 and 2 are working completely fine. I was even able to get my hands on another windows 8 phone and the install worked on that phone as well (we'll call it phone 4). So now I'm still stuck on the same problem with phone 3. Its the same brand as the other phones, downloading the same files from the same wifi connection. I've done a factory reset on the phone three times but still no luck. The phone does not contain a sim card or SD card but none of the others do either so that shouldn't matter.